# When to use CSRF protection?

Tags: php, csrf, csrf-protection

I think the answer to my question is no, but I just wanted some clarification.  I have a webpage which requires no login whatsoever.  Users are essentially anonymous.  The form requires them to fill in personal information, and then upload a couple of sensitive documents.

Considering the sensitive information they will upload, would CSRF protection make sense?  Keep in mind that there is no login required, so I am not too sure if it would be of any use?

Any clarification appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's pretty minimal effort to put it in place, and will at least prevent someone from putting code on a popular web page that submits a bunch of fake submissions to your form.

Comment: true, but isnt the purpose behind it to stop people from pretending to be an authenticated user of some status?  If my page does not have any users, would it be beneficial?

Comment: @kate_hudson — ceejayoz just gave you another use case!

Comment: The purpose is to prevent third parties from making your and/or your users submit HTTP requests they didn't intend. Since you allow non-privileged users to submit a form, that's a potential attack vector. The danger posed by this is fairly small - you'd just get a bunch of useless submissions on the form - but it's up to you if that matters. There's virtually no downside in being careful and implementing CSRF anyways.

Answer (score -4):

CSRF basically prevents an attacker do something in another user's name (through that user's machine and internet connection). If you are worried about that (e.g. you record IP addresses and you don't want an attacker to send a request with someone else's IP, or record someone else's IP against their will), you should use CSRF protection. If you are not worried about it, you should use CSRF protection anyway, it's a good practice :) but you don't *need* to.

Also, CSRF cannot be used to upload files (barring browser bugs or very permissive CORS settings).